# Wikidata SPARQL, why an intermediate item is needed in this sample query?

Tags: wikidata, sparql

In the [Wikidata SPARQL samples](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/SPARQL_Query_Examples#What_is_the_relation_between_Terrell_Buckley_and_Miami_Dolphins.3F), I found this query:

**What is the relation between Terrell Buckley and Miami Dolphins?**
*Items used: Terrell Buckley (Q5571382), Miami Dolphins (Q223243)*

```
SELECT ?l 
WHERE
{
    wd:Q5571382 ?p wd:Q223243 .
    ?property ?ref ?p .
    ?property a wikibase:Property .
    ?property rdfs:label ?l FILTER (lang(?l) = "en")
}
LIMIT 10
```

[Try it](http://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fl%20%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09wd%3AQ5571382%20%3Fp%20wd%3AQ223243%20.%0A%09%3Fproperty%20%3Fref%20%3Fp%20.%0A%09%3Fproperty%20a%20wikibase%3AProperty%20.%0A%09%3Fproperty%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fl%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fl%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%2010)

I found really hard to know why you can't simply write:

```
SELECT ?l 
WHERE
{
    wd:Q5571382 ?property wd:Q223243 .
    ?property a wikibase:Property .
    ?property rdfs:label ?l FILTER (lang(?l) = "en")
}
LIMIT 10
```

Removing the ?p intermediate variable.

The fact it doesn't work numbs me beyond comprehension, I don't know if I'm simply too stupid to understand it, but, could you help me, guys?

Comment: BTW, I think for questions about SPARQ, you have a better chance of getting an answer at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @svick , I'll take that into account, but, I think it's not about the language (both ways are perfectly valid SPARQL), but the content of wikidata graphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original query `?property` and `?p` are distinct values: `?property` is `wd:P54` (short for `<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P54>`) and `?p` is `wdt:P54` (short for `<http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P54>`). Notice that both refer to P54, but they are not the same. The two are connected by `?ref`, which is `wikibase:directClaim`.

This is why your simplified query doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, I already found that, the wdt vs wd issue but, the question is, why in the world they decided to separate the Properties metadata into another namespace?. I don't see the advantages of such approach. Have you any clues?